# How to design data in MongoDB which come from relational DB?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am coming from relational database world so please excuse the simplicity of my question.

As I learnt in MongoDB we can store documents so we don't have to denormalize our data.
However I am at a loss how to design the following simple data coming from a relational DB:
I have a STATUS_LOG table which contains status about the progressing of a process (like 'Started', 'Found XXX entities to process', 'Error: ...', etc). Let's assume the process is stored in EXTRACTION table (it contains lots of other attributes along with other child tables) so in relational DB I'd have something like:

```
STATUS_LOG         EXTRACTION
----------         ----------
ID                 ID
...                ...
EXTRACTION_ID
```

AFAIK we don't like to use joins in noSQL DB so what can I do to store the same in MongoDB?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This actually depends on a lot of context and the actual scenario. I would suggest [this official MongoDB blog post](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design) as a starting point.